# UIAlertView or Modal Popover for a EULA?

Tags: iphone, uialertview, uipopovercontroller

I was wondering what different things ppl have done for a EULA page?  We have some legal disclosures to present and want the user to click a checkbox saying they agree to those terms.  If they don't agree, don't let them use the app.  I know in iOS 5, they added some new features to UIAlertView, but I don't see a checkbox option.  I see they have the `UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput` that maybe I could use to ask the user to put in their name, verify it, and then let them use the app if it matches the credentials on our webserver.

Or simply present a Modal popover with a checkbox button that has to be checked for the popover to disappear.  This option seems easier to me, but I'm not sure what other ppl have done.  Thanks.

Comment: Aren't EULAs meant to be entered in iTunes Connect and displayed in the App Store? I imagine that presenting a EULA to the user upon initial launch may be cause for rejection by Apple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A popover generally has to have a source (i.e. another UI element) that it’s being presented from, which wouldn’t be appropriate in this case, and an alert view is too small to reasonably display the wall-of-text that comprises most EULAs.

Your best option is probably a modal view controller containing a text view (or a web view if you want to be fancy), presented with its `modalPresentationStyle` set to `UIModalPresentationFormSheet`. Stick a “yes, I read this and accept” button that closes the view controller in there and you should be good to go.